# Does Excel as something similar to SQL "Except"?

Tags: sql, excel, except

I am able to perform Union of two tables in MS Query of excel but its throwing error for "Except".
Can someone please let me know is there anyway to use "Except" of two tables in Excel.

SELECT * FROM [Book1query] tbl2 
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM [Merge1] tbl1

Answer (score 0):

EXCEPT returns only rows, which are not available in the second SELECT statement. In other words, a join type of left anti.

In Power Query you can do that with a Merge of two tables, using the Join Kind option for Left Anti.

For a detailed description of all the Join Kind options, visit https://radacad.com/choose-the-right-merge-join-type-in-power-bi

[image]

Comment: if that solved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]